# Know the username of a user trying to logged

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, pam

I've a debian system, when a user try to login, a pam module exec a bash script as root.
I need this script to know who is trying to login.

But the user isn't already connected so basic command as users/w/who ... doesn't work here.

So is there a possibility to retrieve the username of a user trying to get logged ?

Thank you.
Cyrbil

Comment: Solved: Simply, $PAM_USER contains the actual username trying to loggin

Comment: Please make your comment an answer and accept it, this shows others that the question is answered.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thiton: can't answer my own question, need to wait 7 hours ...
Topic solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc` to grab the user logging in, I typically have a small script that gets executed via `/etc/bashrc` that gives me details about the user (who it is, connecting from what IP address etc).